# Where are the sidecar files AAE located in Finder?

Tags: photos

I'd like to know where the sidecar files for Photos are located in the Mac (Finder).

Thank you.

Comment: In Terminal: `find / -type f -iname *.aae 2>/dev/null`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  I've edited several pictures and this command just returned a hit I had seen before I edited them (result: /Users/MyUserName/Pictures/IMG_1337.AAE)  I also tried find / -type f -iname ".aae" 2>/dev/null.  Aren't these sidecars stored in a typical folder in Finder?.  Thanks for your answer anyway, I know it's a bit frustrating not to be understood.

Comment: isn't this the same as creating a smart folder to look for File Extension:AAE? would that locate AEE files wherever they are?

Comment: If you want to check for directories and files just leave the `-type f` out of the command and `find` will look at all types.

Comment: Yes, you can setup a Smart Folder; however, depending on what one is looking for it may not show up even though it exists and is why I choose to use the `find` command as it will find thing Finder doesn't

Comment: Thanks for that, note taken.  However, I can't find these AAE files even though I've edited a few photos.

Comment: I learnt that macOS doesn't save edits in sidecar files.  See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250288805?answerId=250540789022&page=1