# When are sidecar AAE files created in a Mac?

Tags: photos

I'm trying to figure out how the Photos app works.

I had the idea that each time you start to edit a photo, a sidecar (AAE) file is created.

However, I edited several photos and I couldn't find any AAE files created.  Where are the sidecar files that should have been created?

I'm searching AAE files with a Terminal search:
find / -type f -iname *.aae 2>/dev/null

Any help much welcome.

Comment: You need  find / -type f -iname "*.aae"  2>/dev/null;  WIthout quoting your search string, the *.aae expands in your current directory.  This list of files is then searched in all your other directories. The find command never sees the "*".  Placing the quotes means the find command will see the "*".  The find command will expand the search in every directory.

Comment: @historystamp, I posted that `find` command as a comment to the duplicate question and looking at my bash history I did have it quoted and when I typed it in the comment I didn't quote it, an oversight on my part; however, quoted or not it actually found the target file spec.

Comment: You didn't actually get an answer on your original question. Why don't you edit the things you've tried into your original question and we take it from there?

Comment: @user3439894 Can I encourage you to post a full answer beneath the original question and also include the location your `find` command managed to find the files?

Comment: @nohillside, I posted the `find` command in a comment to the OP's original question as an alternative to Finder. I did not have any `.aae` files on my system but I also do not use Photos to manipulate photos. I did however create via `touch` a `foobar.aae` file to test the command and it did find it. So if any do exist on the OP's system that command should find them.

Comment: @user3439894 I use Photos, also to manipulate pictures, but didn‘t find any aae files at all

Comment: I answered in my first question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356228/where-are-the-sidecar-files-aae-located-in-finder

Comment: I learnt that macOS doesn't save edits in sidecar files.  See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250288805?answerId=250540789022&page=1